# How to set the cached file contents in the index to arbitrary content

Tags: git

How can I set the cached file contents in the index of a path to arbitrary content without modifying the file(s) in the working tree? For example, I want to be able to set the cached file contents of `some_file.xml` to the contents of a temporary file without changing the contents of `some_file.xml`.

The point of this is that I have written an XSL stylesheet that removes sensitive information from certain XML files. I would like to write a script that can replace the cached file contents of the XML files with the transformed XML;  i.e. `some_file.xml` is transformed with the XSL to `.some_file.xml.tmp` and the script should update the index for `some_file.xml` with the contents of `.some_file.xml.tmp` without affecting the contents of `some_file.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git hash-object -t blob -w .some_file.xml.tmp` to insert the contents of the temp file as a blob in the object database. The sha1 of this blob is returned on stdout. You can then use this sha1 with `git update-index --index-info` or `git update-index --cacheinfo`.